# How to solve this error in MySql Query syntax in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is The Error I am getting..

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`Sensor` = 'sklfj', `Lens` = 'lkjsdf', `IR` = 'lkjdsf', `Audio` = 'kjlasf', `WDR' at line 1

```
UPDATE `hdtvicameras_spec`
SET `Resolution` = 'd',
 `Image` `Sensor` = 'sklfj',
 `Lens` = 'lkjsdf',
 `IR` = 'lkjdsf',
 `Audio` = 'kjlasf',
 `WDR` = 'lkjsf1',
 `ICR` = 'klasjf',
 `IP` `Rating` = 'lkjsdf',
 `Zoom` = 'ljs'
WHERE
    `product_id` = '46'
```

**Product_model.php**

```
$this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
$this->db->update($tbname, $spec_array);
```

After `var_dump($spec_array)` this is what I get

```
array(10) { 
    ["Resolution"]=> string(5) "first" 
    ["Image Sensor"]=> string(6) "second" 
    ["Lens"]=> string(6) "third " 
    ["IR"]=> string(6) "fourth" 
    ["Audio"]=> string(6) "fifthe" 
    ["WDR"]=> string(6) "sisxth" 
    ["ICR"]=> string(5) "seven" 
    ["IP Rating"]=> string(5) "eight" 
    ["Zoom"]=> string(4) "nine" 
    ["SD Card"]=> string(3) "ten" 
}
```

All those key values in array are fetched from database which is specification names of any product.

looks like there is some error with space in key name. Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: Here you need to change `Image` `Sensor` to `ImageSensor` or some thing else in to your `$spec_array`.

Comment: @MayankVadiya thanks... i used this function str_replace(' ','_",$specification); So that if there will be any space it will be replaced by '_' .. so that it will not cause any trouble in future... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have error here:

> ```
> `Image` `Sensor` = 'sklfj',
> ```

After image you didn't give the value to it.

Comment: Actually `Image Sensor` is only one property... it defines whether camera contains image sensor or not....
Can we use Space in key names??

Comment: so use the backtick correctly `ImageSensor` like this

Answer (score 3):

use query like this and check:

```
UPDATE `hdtvicameras_spec`
SET `Resolution` = 'd',
 `Image Sensor` = 'sklfj',
 `Lens` = 'lkjsdf',
 `IR` = 'lkjdsf',
 `Audio` = 'kjlasf',
 `WDR` = 'lkjsf1',
 `ICR` = 'klasjf',
 `IP Rating` = 'lkjsdf',
 `Zoom` = 'ljs'
WHERE `product_id` = '46'
```

Since you added quotes, for fields names having more then 1 word, its showing error.

Answer (score 1):

Since Image Sensor is a column with space in it, therefore you are getting an error. CI is adding **`** to every field with a space. It is not a good practice to use a space in your columns in MySQL.

In order to solve this problem, either you should remove space or write a query in below mentioned form and pass it in `$this->db->query()`.

```
UPDATE `hdtvicameras_spec` 
SET `Resolution` = 'd', `Image Sensor` = 'sklfj', `Lens` = 'lkjsdf', `IR` = 'lkjdsf', `Audio` = 'kjlasf', `WDR` = 'lkjsf1', `ICR` = 'klasjf', `IP Rating` = 'lkjsdf', `Zoom` = 'ljs' 
WHERE `product_id` = '46'
```

Comment: Ohh... Got that.. I changed every table containing space and replaced it with '_' ...
Thanks.. :)